# Qual è la forma corretta 'hanno contato' o 'sono contati'?

Tags: word-choice, verbs, auxiliary-verb

> ... gli attivisti del partito non hanno contato mai nulla per i vertici ...
>
> ... gli attivisti del partito non sono contati mai nulla per i vertici ...

Qual è la forma corretta, 'hanno contato' o 'sono contati'?

Comment: *sono contanti* sarebbe corretto se il verbo *contare* fosse stato usato nel senso di *enumerare*, sebbene suoni molto male usare la forma passiva (*le mele sono contate da Pierino* suona molto peggio di *Pierino conta le mele*).

Answer (score 9):

The correct one is "gli attivisti del partito non hanno contato mai nulla". In fact, "[contare](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/contare/)" is here an intransitive verb requiring the auxiliary "avere".

Comment: tra l'altro, io direi "non hanno mai contato nulla", anticipare il "mai" suona meglio.

Comment: It's what I would too, putting _mai_ before _contato_.

Comment: While I agree that it "sounds better", intransitive verbs require the auxiliary "essere". "*Ho* mangiato la pasta", "*sono* caduto dal letto".